# How to show data in a page temporally untill user confirms them?

Tags: asp.net, session, caching

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET.
I have a page where users can put advertisements to my website. So he has to select the location , ad category type the contact details and post the ad. So after finishing it he has to press the button Proceed.

Then I hope to took him to a new page which showing him how exactly his ad will show in my website. So if he has to do some modifications he can go back and again he has to press the Proceed button after editing it. If he satisfied he can confirms the ad an then the records should add to my database.

So I am wondering where to temporary keep these data and show in the page?

My idea is to store these details in sessions or in cache. I think session will be good. But people are saying that you should avoid using sessions at all cost because it eat ups the memory in server. What I am going to display are not critical data. So I dont want any security regarding the data. So tell me what is the best way to show user's entered data in a another page temporally until user confirm it?

Comment: Storing these kind of data in session, I don't think its a good way!! Can't you store them in a class or similar?

Comment: You mean use value object class to temporally store data right? Then I have to retrieve data from that class right?

Comment: Yes, but i am not sure what you are using at the moment. You can use JSON

Comment: I am following 3 tier architecture. Currently I am using value object classes to pass data between different layers.

Comment: Good, so you can serialize the object into a JSON and pass it to the POST body, or even you can use ViewState

Comment: Since I am going for completely different page View-state is not useful right?

Comment: I prefer the JSON approach